# Two-way binding Angular component property to AngularJS view

Tags: angularjs, angular, data-binding

So we have an application written in AngularJS, slowly migrating to Angular component-wise.

I'm now building a simple reusable component that is basically a dropdown box with a label. This is of course in Angular - so I downgrade it into AngularJS, then use it in an AngularJS view.

How can I now two-way bind a property from the component (let's call it `MyDropdown.CurrentValue`) to a scope variable of the AngularJS view (let's call it `$scope.numberOfCarsOwned`)?

The component of course has both `@Input() CurrentValue: any;` and `@Output() CurrentValueChange: EventEmitter<any>`, bound to the inner dropdown box.

In Angular, I'd just go `<MyDropdown [(CurrentValue)]="numberOfCarsOwned" />`, but how do I do this when integrating the component (downgraded as a directive) into my AngularJS view?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, once you know how to do it it's totally easy:

In the AngularJS view, you use it as if you were in Angular:

```
<MyComponent
  [(CurrentValue)]="numberOfCarsOwned"
></MyComponent>
```

This will automagically bind the `CurrentValue` (using the component's `CurrentValueChange`) to the view's `$scope.numberOfCarsOwned`.